# Готовые решения для отображения CRUD над “моделью” (entity), есть такие?

Tags: android, gui, activity

У меня есть "модель" или entity, скажем это User. Мне нужно

- отобразить всех пользователей
- иметь возможность отредактировать одного
- иметь возможность добавить нового
- иметь возможность удалить одного

Как сделать сами crud операции - я знаю.

Мне интересно, есть какие-то готовые или полуготовые решения или шаблоны для **отображения** (layout'ы, контролы) всего этого?

Конечно, я могу сделать все вручную - взять 4 activity, добавить на одну list view (список всех), на другую textview и editView (редактирование) и т.п. Но, наверняка что-то должно быть потому готовое/полуготовое. Например, в Rails это называется scaffolding и генерится автоматически.

Android 4.3 и выше.

Answer (score 1):

Тут 4 активити не нужно. я лично вижу 2 скрина, первый скрин, он же главный, отображает список item'ов, по долгому тапу на item - удаление long-тапнутой сущности из списка (можно уточнять через диалог), по тапу - открывать скрин для редактирования item'а (edit-скрин), еще на главном скрине я бы добавил FAB-кнопку для добавления нового item'а(new-скрин), по нажатию на который будет открываться скрин, аналогичный edit-скрину, но только пустой, по сути это будет один скрин, отличие можно передавать через Bundle в интенте.
Так что все очень стандартно для Андроида))

И да, как уж вы реализуете эти два скрина -  или 2 активити или 1 активити и 2 фрагмента - это уже ваше дело.